# Putting social buttons on all webpages using 1 single code

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, twitter

[jsfidllde](http://jsfiddle.net/E2u3b/1/)

I am trying to get the lazy load effect of social buttons through socialite.js. Everything is fine, but the +1s, likes, tweet counter is for socialite.com and not my website. For example, this code gives socialite.com a "like":

```
<li>
  <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.socialitejs.com&amp;t=Socialite.js"
     class="socialite facebook-like" data-href="http://socialitejs.com" data-send="false"
     data-layout="box_count" data-width="60" data-show-faces="false" rel="nofollow"
     target="_blank"><span class="vhidden">Share on Facebook</span></a>
</li>
```

I want it to be for my page. Manually changing http://socialitejs.com to mywebsite.com for each and every different page is too tiresome.

I believe there is a trick to do this with javascript and replacing `href` with `expr:share_url='data:post.url'`, however this is not working as the code has many other attributes apart from `href`. Can anyone help me please. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Trying to fix the **generated** markup will surely be much harder than fixing the **source** markup...

Answer (score 0):

When you add the element in which you'll invoke socialite.js:

```
<a class="socialite twitter-share" href="http://twitter.com/share" data-url="http://socialitejs.com">
    Share on Twitter
</a>
```

You're supposed to replace the value at `data-url` for your website URL. Then the generated elements will point to your website.

If you, by mistake, already included the wrong URL in many places - and feel it's easier to correct it with JavaScript instead of doing search-and-replace in a bunch of files - then I suggest running this jQuery line **before** calling `Socialite.load()`:

```
$('[data-url]').attr('data-url', 'mywebsite.com');
```